# Two unknowns: one vector, one scalar, one equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, multilinear-algebra

#### I would like to know if this equation is solvable for $a$ and $\alpha$:

\begin{equation}
\Sigma = \Gamma + a \left( \alpha 1^\top + 1\alpha^\top  \right) +a^2 b
\end{equation}

---

1. $\Sigma$ & $\Gamma$ are known. Both are $D\times D$ matrices.
2. $\Sigma$ is symmetric positive definite.
3. $\Gamma$ is symmetric positive semi definite.
4. $\alpha$ is a $D$ vector.
5. $\sum_{i=0}^D \alpha_i =0$.
6. $a$ is a scalar.
7. $b$ is a $1$s matrix of $D\times D$.
8. The $1$ is a $D$ vector of $1$s .

If it is solvable, can you explain how?

Comment: Is the question whether a solution exists, whether a solution exists and is unique, whether there is a "closed form" solution (whatever that means), whether there is an efficient algorithm to find the/a solution, or some combination?

Comment: you have $D+1$ equations with $D+1$ unknowns, so this should generically give you a solution; I doubt more can be said in full generality.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431425/two-unknowns-one-vector-one-scalar-one-equation#comment1110394_431425), isn't it $\frac{D(D + 1)}2$ scalar equations?  Is there some further obvious redundancy than the symmetry?

Comment: @LSpice I believe the question is whether a solution exists, whether a solution exists and is unique between each variable. Yes, for a closed form solution (so not infinite sum or limit etc). I'm not asking for an efficient algorithm. Just basically how can you solve for both variables

Comment: Please have pity on an aged mathematician with failing eyesight, and avoid using both “$a$” and “$\alpha$” in the same formula, and above all next to each other.

Comment: Yes sir, sorry sir 

Comment: @Lubin This applies to mathematicians in their early 40s too...

Comment: What is "a 1s matrix of $D\times D$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small rearrangement yields
$$
\Sigma-\Gamma = a(\alpha + a 1 )1^T + a1 \alpha^T.
$$
So for solvability the rank of $\Sigma-\Gamma$ can at most be $2$.

If $\mathrm{rank}\ \Sigma-\Gamma = 0$, then $\Sigma = \Gamma$. Then a solution is $a=0$ and any $\alpha$ with $\alpha^T1=0$. If we assume $a\neq 0$ we equivalently need to solve
$$
0 = \alpha 1^T + 1 \alpha^T + a 11^T
$$
This implies $\alpha$ is a nonzero multiple of $1$ contradicting the requirement $\alpha^T1=0$. So if $\Sigma = \Gamma$ the solution set is
$$
M = \{ (a,\alpha) | a=0, \alpha^T1=0\}.
$$

For the other cases first note that $\mathrm{rank}\ \Sigma-\Gamma >0 $ implies $a\neq 0$. Furthermore, if you multiply the original equation from left and right by $1^T$ and $1$ you obtain that any solution would have to verify the scalar equation
$$
1^T (\Sigma-\Gamma) 1 = a^2 D^2. \tag{$*$}\label{star}
$$
The other terms vanish because $\alpha^T 1=0$ by assumption. This gives you two potential values for $a$. Also we obtain the next necessary condition that $1^T (\Sigma-\Gamma) 1 \neq 0$ (or even $>0$ if you are looking  for real solutions).

When you plug these in the equation is linear in $\alpha$. So for the two potential values of $a$ we need to solve (using $a\neq 0$)
$$
\frac{1}{a}(\Sigma-\Gamma) - a 1 1^T= \alpha 1^T + 1 \alpha^T.
$$
Using $\alpha^T 1 =0$, we get from muliplication by $1$ and division by $D$ that
$$
\frac{1}{aD}(\Sigma-\Gamma)1 - a 1= \alpha.\tag{$**$}\label{starstar}
$$
This at least satisfies $\alpha^T 1 =0$ as from \eqref{star} we get
$$
\alpha^T 1 = \frac{1}{aD}1^T(\Sigma-\Gamma)1 - a D = 0.
$$
So if there is a solution for the two possible $a$'s then it is given by the $\alpha$ from \eqref{starstar}. But note that this does not have to be a solution. This would still depend on $\Sigma - \Gamma$.